# how to give a subdomain name in the main domain file.?

Tags: html, ftp, filezilla

I try to give sub domain name as a link in the main domain file, but it can't be upload in 
    the ftp server, I am using file zilla. when I try to upload the file, it  automatically
   deleted. sub domain is the problem, is there any solution to upload it in a ftp.?? I try it 
    with all possible ways, like using PHP, website name is stored in a variable, still it is 
    not upload in the server. it only upload when it remove the sub  domain name, can any one 
    help me for this problem.??
    thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
finnaly i got the solution for my problem, encrypt the subdomain name and it will given to 
the page, and that is decrypted while using...
```